# parsing failed [TypeError: Network request failed] Expo, react-native

Tags: react-native, http, https, fetch, expo

I have made some little app that should read Barcodes and send the data via API.

example:

```
handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {

    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned! and the phone is ${this.state.maci`);

    var BarCodeScannedInApp = 'http://localhost:50474/api/ScanPart?PartBarCode=' + data + "&StationName=" + this.state.maci;
    fetch(BarCodeScannedInApp)
      .then(response => response.json())

    .catch(error => console.log('parsing failed', error))
  };
```

When the code trying to execute the Fetch it’s throwing an exception “parsing failed [TypeError: Network request failed]”

- tried to change the LocalHost to my actual IP address but it didnt help me.

```
app.json:
```

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my-test-scan",
    "slug": "my-test-scan",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you see the request on your API in a log or something ?

Comment: I think it fails when it tries to make the call, can't catch it with the debugger on the server side... @colinux